# How to reduce the empty space between the columns of a multiple plot layout?

Tags: r, graphics, scatter-plot, smoothing

There is a lot of empty space between two plots of the same row. I tried to rectify this by changing the outer margins and plot margins using par() but it isn't working. Another solution I thought of was to increase the size of individual plots but I don't know how to.

```
layout(matrix(1:8, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))
par(oma=c(5,0.1,1,1), mar=c(5,0.1,1,1),  pty="s")

plot(Annual.Rainfall.in.mm ~ Year, data=AnnRF, ylab = "Rainfall (mm)", sub="(a)", col="blue", bg="blue", pch=21, cex.lab = 1.4)
lines(lowess(AnnRF$Year, AnnRF$Annual.Rainfall.in.mm), col="red", lwd=3)

plot(Annual.Rainy.Days ~ Year, data=AnnRD, ylab = "Rainy Days", sub="(b)", col="blue", bg="blue", pch=21, cex.lab = 1.4)
lines(lowess(AnnRD$Year, AnnRD$`Annual.Rainy.Days`), col="red", lwd=3)

plot(Monsoon.Rainfall.in.mm ~ Year, data=MonRF, ylab = "Rainfall (mm)", sub="(c)", col="blue", bg="blue", pch=21, cex.lab = 1.4)
lines(lowess(MonRF$Year, MonRF$`Monsoon.Rainfall.in.mm`), col="red", lwd=3)

plot(Monsoon.Rainy.Days ~ Year, data=MonRD, ylab = "Rainy Days", sub="(d)", col="blue", bg="blue", pch=21, cex.lab = 1.4)
lines(lowess(MonRD$Year, MonRD$`Monsoon.Rainy.Days`), col="red", lwd=3)

plot(Pre.Monsoon.Rainfall.in.mm ~ Year, data=PreRF, ylab = "Rainfall (mm)", sub="(e)", col="blue", bg="blue", pch=21, cex.lab = 1.4)
lines(lowess(PreRF$Year, PreRF$`Pre.Monsoon.Rainfall.in.mm`), col="red", lwd=3) 

plot(Pre.Monsoon.Rainy.Days ~ Year, data=PreRD, ylab = "Rainy Days", sub="(f)", col="blue", bg="blue", pch=21, cex.lab = 1.4)
lines(lowess(PreRD$Year, PreRD$`Pre.Monsoon.Rainy.Days`), col="red", lwd=3)

plot(Post.Monsoon.Rainfall.in.mm ~ Year, data=PostRF, ylab = "Rainfall (mm)", sub="(g)", col="blue", bg="blue", pch=21, cex.lab = 1.4)
lines(lowess(PostRF$Year, PostRF$`Post.Monsoon.Rainfall.in.mm`), col="red", lwd=3)

plot(Post.Monsoon.Rainy.Days ~ Year, data=PostRD, ylab = "Rainy Days", sub="(h)", col="blue", bg="blue", pch=21, cex.lab = 1.4)
lines(lowess(PostRD$Year, PostRD$`Post.Monsoon.Rainy.Days`), col="red", lwd=3)
```

[image: Rplot]

Comment: The wide gap is due to `pty = "s"` which is saying plot in a square region. Try with `pty = "m"` to get a maximal plot. Your plots will be rectangular. Or is your question how to get square plots in two columns closer to each other?

Comment: @Peter I have obtained the rectangular plots too as per your suggestion but it would be preferable to get the plots closer to each other while maintaining the square shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the plot by controlling with overall width and height of the image i.e. plot page size, for example, as a png file.

The argument `pty = "s"` forces a square plot. So by playing around with the width and height arguments of the plot page size you can get the appearance you want.

Alternatively you can use the `respect` argument of `layout` and use `cex.lab` to vary the axis label size.

```r
layout(matrix(1:8, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE), respect = TRUE)

par(oma=c(0, 0, 0, 0), 
    mar=c(5,4,1,1),  
    pty="s")

for(i in 1:8) plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Length, sub = i,
                   cex.lab = 1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: So changing the width and height of the png will also change the spacing between the individual plots as well? In your output, I just want to reduce the spacing between the plots which are in the same row.

Comment: I am sorry I do not quite follow what you are saying. Are you wanting to control both horizontal and vertical spacing between plots? Perhaps a sketch of what you want to achieve would clarify the question?

Comment: The output is a 4 X 2 multi plot figure with no. of rows = 4 and no. of columns = 2 right? Now, if you look at the two plots in the same row (horizontally/left and right), there is a lot of empty white space in between. I want to reduce that space so that the two plots lie close to each other while retaining their square shape and the individual axes labels.

Comment: That's what I thought. Could you please explain how does the answer not achieve this?

Comment: Changing the width and height doesn't reduce the empty space between the plots. Instead, the size of the layout changes which also reduces the size of plots and the axes labels making them unreadable.

Comment: May be you are looking to use the `respect` argument? See updated answer

Comment: It took me too long to realise that manually changing the size of the window (by dragging its corners) where the plots appear also changed the dimensions of the exported image. I assumed it was just a UI thing, kind of like a functionality added for better viewing of the plot which was limited to the software. I had no idea that the changes are actually transferred to the exported image as well. Now I feel dumb.